# Combine Multiple Rows in one in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have oracle table data as below:

```
ID  ColA   ColB   ColC    ColD   ColE   ColF
1   null   null   null      D1     E1    F1
1   A1     B1      C1      null   null   null 
1   A2     B2      C2      null   null   null
```

I want to have records like

```
ID   ColA    ColB   ColC    ColD   ColE   ColF
1    A1      B1     C1      D1      E1     F1
1    A2      B2     C2      D1      E1     F1
```

Basically,
Single ID can have multiple ColA rows,and ColD,E and F will always be null for these. 
So at all ID@ColA combinations(Where ColA is not null) I want to populate D,E and F with the values corresponding to ColD,E and F of the same ID where ColA is null

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach I can see here is to self join your table on the following three conditions:

- The `ID` values match
- The `ColA`, `ColB`, and `ColC` values on the left side of the join are not `NULL`, and
- The `ColD`, `ColE`, and `ColF` values on the right side of the join are not `NULL`

The following query would work, at least for the sample data you did show us:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.ColA,
    t1.ColB,
    t1.ColC,
    t2.ColD,
    t2.ColE,
    t2.ColF
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE
    t1.ColA IS NOT NULL AND
    t1.ColB IS NOT NULL AND
    t1.ColC IS NOT NULL AND
    t2.ColD IS NOT NULL AND
    t2.ColE IS NOT NULL AND
    t2.ColF IS NOT NULL;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks Tim. Any other way apart from joining the same table, as the data set I posted is formed by multiple subqueries involving UNION. So I dont want to mess up the performance also.

Comment: You are asking a fairly different question now, not what you actually posted.  No, I don't see any other way of handling your requirement besides the self join approach I used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `MAX` analytical function to fill all the details in blank `COLD`, `COLE` and `COLF` columns and then `where clause` will be required to filter out the first row from your sample data where `COLA`, `COLB` and `COLC` are all nulls.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID,
            COLA,
            COLB,
            COLC,
            MAX(COLD) OVER(
                PARTITION BY ID
            ) AS COLD,
            MAX(COLE) OVER(
                PARTITION BY ID
            ) AS COLE,
            MAX(COLF) OVER(
                PARTITION BY ID
            ) AS COLF
        FROM
            YOUR_TABLE
    )
WHERE
    COLA IS NOT NULL
    AND COLB IS NOT NULL
    AND COLC IS NOT NULL;
```

Cheers!!